# CartThrob Reducing Inventory By a Factor of 2

Tags: cartthrob, checkout, order-info

If someone orders 1x a product at some point between “checkout” and “order_info” in the sample files with CTv2.2 the inventory of the item gets reduced by double (in this case 2).

Why does it think it needs to reduce the inventory by 2x the ordered amount?

- [View Cart template](http://pastebin.com/CHiB4JGB)
- [Checkout form](http://pastebin.com/mJfsXAwS)
- [Order Info tag](http://pastebin.com/g1hwJj0c)

Thanks.

EE 2.5.3
CT 2.2.2

Comment: Has this only just started happening since 2.2? Is there any more information you can give us as to when this started happening? What have you tried so far to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using to generate the checkout form(s).

Comment: @adrian » This is our first use of CT so we have no comparison to prior versions.

Comment: @foamcow » not sure how to post sample code. Seems to be character limits on posts.

Comment: Could you use pastebin.com and post the link to you paste here?

Comment: 1. view cart: http://pastebin.com/CHiB4JGB
2. checkout: http://pastebin.com/mJfsXAwS
3. order_info: http://pastebin.com/g1hwJj0c

Comment: @MikeDexter I've included your sample code in the question so that people won't miss them.

Comment: In general try to reduce your code to the smallest possible excerpt which still causes an issue.

Comment: @AdrianMacneil » From what I can tell we are using the bare bones of code. These are the super simple samples that come with CT 2.2. From the samples I've supplied, what would you suggest I remove - I don't think we can remove anything and still have it function.

Comment: Does the cart show 2 items where it should show 1? The bit that controls inventory is the add to cart form. It would be worth looking there.

Comment: this is the thing... the cart looks perfect. right quantities, right dollar amounts etc. it's JUST the inventory figure that is being doubled

Comment: Yes, but in the add to cart form, not the cart itself, the "buy now" button as it were. This is where I *think* you need to look. I'll post some info in an answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that there is a bug in CartThrob 2.2 with regards to managing inventory: http://cartthrob.com/forums/viewthread/7374/

[image: how to reproduce the error]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the code you are using for the add to cart bit.

Normally, with CartThrob, you would use {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form} to do the "buy now" bit.

If you look at the docs for this tag pair...

http://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/add_to_cart_form/index.html

You will see that you can specify a quantity parameter in the tag pair.
However, you can *also* add a form field to allow for custom quantities - i.e. you can add more than 1 product at a time to your cart.

I may well be wrong, but I have a feeling you have both the quantity parameter AND a quantity field. Just a hunch. To be honest I don't know what would happen if you did but it's my best guess with the info so far.

Comment: I have stripped my add to cart page down to nothing, and only used the CT sample code from the docs (http://pastebin.com/YdVsb1g5). It still updates the inventory by double what was actually bought.